# Extract xml tag value from XML column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am working with xml datatype columns in SQL Server. I know how to extract the values from XML columns by using `query()` or `value()` functions but my problem is slightly different.

In my database table the XML has no fixed pattern. This means, the XML tags are not fixed and varying in most of the records.

As an example:

```
<Types>
  <request>
    <Rollcount>34</Rollcount>
  </request>
</Types>

<Types>
  <general>
    <Rollcount>5</Rollcount>
  </general>
</Types>

<Types>
  <land>
     <Rollcount>21</Rollcount>
  <land>
</Types>
```

In above example you can see, XML has different tags like `<request>`, `<general>` and `<land>`. There is no fixed pattern.

Now I want to extract a value of `<Rollcount>`. Could you please tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wildcards. If we assume that the top nodes is always `Types`, and `Rollcount` is always the 3rd level then you could do this:

```sql
DECLARE @XML xml ='<Types>
  <general>
    <Rollcount>5</Rollcount>
  </general>
</Types>';

SELECT X.RC.value('.','int')
FROM @XML.nodes('Types/*/Rollcount')X(RC);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3abfc5a5cc93416e5e68b144ec08e828)